# Ajax returns error

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ url: "/TheControllerName/MyMethod",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json", dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('something');
    },
    error: function (httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
    }
})//end of ajax call
```

Here is the method:

```
    public JsonResult MyMethod()
    {
        //get some list
        return Json(theList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The method is getting called and the breakpoint comes out of it succesfully but I get this error: 500 (Internal Server Error) status=error,error=Internal Server Error

Comment: is theList initialized?  is there an exception on the server that you can check in the logs?

Comment: @user1357437 Yes, theList has ok values. The server doesn't throw errors.

Comment: if you are getting a internal server error of 500 there is an error on the server somewhere.  can you turn logging on for the Json method.

Comment: @user1357437 But when I write the method in url, it works fine.

Comment: That is odd, but there is definitely something going wrong on the server, http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E500.html  So if you can get some logs going on you can maybe figure it out.  why do you set the contentType: to json, try not setting the accept to json instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the accept type to json and not the content-type, the reason it works when you enter the url is because this isnt set